# Android - adding scroll view and fixed footer in scroll view with scrollable footer content

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I am working on a Ui design where i have to design a view which is totally scrollable. Inside this view i have a view pager and a fixed footer at the bottom but this footer also gets scrolled when user scroll the content in vertical direction. Now the footer here has long description but that is not suppose to be visible without scrolling. On scrolling in horizontal direction the view pager will work and footer appears to be fixed at the bottom.

Here is my code.

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFooter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="100" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="80"
                        android:text="some dummy textl and Prevention"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageviewViewExpander"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:src="@drawable/page_circle_arrow_down" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textveiw"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:text="some dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy text\nsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy text\nsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy text\nsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy textsome dummy text" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/linearLayoutFooter"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

The problem here is that i have to make the footer stick at the bottom unless the user scrolls and even the view pager content is not visible.

Comment: so do you need the footer to be fixed at bottom, or last item on scrollview, provide an image for better illustration.

Comment: The footer remains at the bottom if user dose not scroll the view in vertical direction. Once he does that the footer also move up but if he is scrolling in horizontal direction the view pager will work to change the content and the footer will remain at it place.

Comment: the problem is you cannat see the footer if you dont scroll down?

Comment: No the footer is visible but there is some content below that which should be visible only if user scrolls the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put your `scrollview` after `RelativeLayout` and before `LinearLayout`
like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
<!--here-->
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFooter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="100" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="80"
                        android:text="Content courtesy of Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageviewViewExpander"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:src="@drawable/page_circle_arrow_down" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewDiseaseControl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:text="To help recognize a concussion, you should watch for and ask others to report the following two things among your athletes:\n\nA forceful bump, blow, or jolt to the head or body that results in rapid movement of the head.\n\nAny concussion signs or symptoms, such as a change in the athlete&apos;s behavior, thinking, or physical functioning.\n\nKeep this list of signs and symptoms on hand. Athletes who exhibit or report one or more of the signs and symptoms listed below, or simply say they just &quot;don&apos;t feel right&quot; after a bump, blow, or jolt to the head or body, may have a concussion." >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView><!--here-->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/linearLayoutFooter"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If i put the view pager outside the scroll view then it does not work and even if it worked then the view pager won't be scrollable if it is outside the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Provide scroll view for only that much components which need to be scrolled. Keep other things outside the scroll view. You can keep footer at the bottom of your activity using attributes like

`android:alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: I need to keep the footer in the scroll view.